# how to detect that file download is Complete using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
    var StrPageName = "GPGeneration_Credit.ashx?UniqueID=" + __uniqueId + "&supplierID=" + supplierID + "&CreditID=" + OrderIds;
        window.open(StrPageName);
   // Here I want to detect that File download is Complete or not and then refresh the //page
        location.reload();
```

Please help me sorry for any mistake

Comment: what do you get? any error? can you provide output of your program?

Answer (score 2):

You can set cookie from server side that will indicate that file download is complete. There is some jQuery [plugin](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/) for that